# Is there any standalone desktop wallet that supports WalletConnect?

Tags: wallets, light-clients

I want some desktop or command line wallet to open my old keystore wallet, connect to some online dapp, and be able to manually inspect and approve the transactions generated by the dapp from the wallet application.

Is these such a wallet?

Comment: It’s not recommended to use keystore file online because this makes your wallet more vulnerable to loss of funds. Software method like keystore file should only be used in offline settings by experienced users.